# Classic ASP Formatnumber change when importing to mailbee

Tags: asp-classic

When i load a page to use it as a mail using MailBee (Afterlogic component for classic ASP), the FormatNumber stop working.

this is the ASP:

`response.write FormatNumber(Round(summatot+moms,0),2)`

and this is the output i get when i load the file in the browser:

**6 069,00**

This is the correct format. But when i load the page to mailbee and sending it using this asp:

```
Set oMailer = CreateObject("MailBee.SMTP")
oMailer.LicenseKey =  "REMOVED"
oMailer.ServerName = "localhost"


oMailer.Message.FromAddr = "REMOVED"
oMailer.Message.ToAddr =  "REMOVED"
headern ="REMOVED"
oMailer.Message.Subject = oMailer.Message.ToUTF8(headern)

oMailer.Message.Charset = "utf-8"


url = "http://localhost/xx.store.se/xx.asp?id="&ID

set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
xmlhttp.send ""
oMailer.Message.BodyText = oMailer.Message.ToUTF8(xmlhttp.responseText)


oMailer.Message.BodyFormat = 1


oMailer.Send
```

I get this output in the mail:

**60.6 900,00**

I am a bit confused, and very greatful for any help!

Best Regard
Linus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something about your LCID. Look for it in the include if you are using one.

Try setting it before your format script with:

```
session.LCID = LCID_VALUE_FOR_YOUR_LOCATION
```

or in the page declaration.

Comment: You are a genius.. I thought that it should be enough to have session.LCID set in "global.ASA" so it started every time the page loaded, but it did not work... Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. But pay attention if the other LCID wasn't set by some other part of code that needs it. You can set it to page scope: `<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"  LCID="1046" %>` as the first line of the page, since `Session.LCID` is session wide.